# Grouping previous value in excel

Tags: excel, group

I need the formula to create the Mapping column in the below table

| Id | Name | Group | Mapping |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tyson1 | A | Tyson1 |
| 2 | Tyson2 | B | Tyson2 |
| 3 | Tyson3 | C | Tyson3 |
| 4 | Tyson4 | C | Tyson 3, Tyson 4 |
| 5 | Tyson5 | D | Tyson5 |
| 6 | Tyson6 | F | Tyson6 |
| 7 | Tyson7 | C | Tyson 3, Tyson 4, Tyson7 |

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B2,$C$2:$C2=C2))
```

For dynamic spill array approach use-

```
=BYROW(C2:C8,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(B2:B8,(C2:C8=x)*(ROW(C2:C8)<=ROW(x))))))
```

[image]